# Is it possible to debug node js code that runs before the debugger attaches?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Using the instructions found [here](https://itnext.io/the-absolute-easiest-way-to-debug-node-js-with-vscode-2e02ef5b1bad) I have setup Visual Studio Code to debug my nodejs code.

But it takes the debugger a few seconds to attach to node. And during that few seconds the code just runs.

So a file like this, with a breakpoint on line 1:

```
• 1 console.log('')
```

Will never break because it quits before the debugger attaches.

I can quickly `^c` the code then restart and sometimes catch the debugger but this is unreliable.

Is there an event I can wait for in my code so that I know the debugger is attached and it is safe to continue?

Or is there a better configuration for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the `--inspect-brk` option for node instead of `--inspect`.

so when running your code it would look something like this

```
node --inspect-brk server.js
```